# printing japanese characters in pdf using libharu

Tags: c++, pdf, unicode, libharu

Currently I am using libharu to create pdf file. In the file I have some Japanese characters and they are saving as utf-8 first.

After that, I am using HPDF_UseJPEncodings(m_pdf), HPDF_UseJPFonts(m_pdf) and m_fontStandard = HPDF_GetFont(m_pdf, "MS-Mincho", "90msp-RKSJ-H") to encode.

However, 90msp-RKSJ-H is cmap and not for utf-8, does anyone know how to convert utf-8 to cmap for 90msp-RKSJ-H?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Hey why dont you refer Libharu's support group on google.

Here's the link for the code you want. 
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/libharu/YzXoH_K3OAI

I hope it solves your purpose.